# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll version mismatch error in azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using a dll (MyApp.dll) which references azure storage dll version 7.2.1 through a nuget. I have added a project.json file to my azure function with "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.1" .
I have also uploaded Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage to bin\ directory. My run.csx file just has "new MyApp.Run(req)".

I get following error about missing dll, what else can I change in my azure function to resolve this error? I can use MyApp.dll fine locally.

> The type initializer for '' threw an exception.  Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

Comment: Can you share your project.json and how you're referencing your private assembly from your csx?Also, you shouldn't mix the two approaches. One thing you may also want to try is to use the shared storage assembly by simply adding a reference to your csx: #r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" (delete the project.json and the storage assembly from your bin folder)

Comment: what happens if we have project.json that has a different version of azure storage then the one that is provided by azure function? Adding project.json seems more natural if I am including a dll which references storage dll (as opposed to run.csx file using storage dll directly). I would expect the dll from projects.json to be placed. Btw, I resolved my issue by switching to the same version as azure function. It might however break when azure function switches its storage dll version and my dll doesn't. Can you share documentation about best way to handle such discrepencies?

Comment: Breaking dependency changes would be considered breaking runtime changes, and those are NOT automatically pushed to existing function apps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reference WindowsAzure.Storage yourself in project.json? You shouldn't, because that one is already referenced for you by the environment. You should use #r to reference this one:

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

This is simply set in your function itself.

[learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)